# Padding to last sub-menu item

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have  a menu with submenus and sub-submenus:

```
<nav>
<ul><li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Shop</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1-1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1-2</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2-1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2-2</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 4</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 5</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 6</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Legal</span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 7</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 8</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 9</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 10</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 11</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 12</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 13</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 14</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7qb1wus/

The submenus are always hidden until clicked. I need to add a bottom padding to each last submenu, so that there is more space below each submenu, EXCEPT for the very last submenu - this one should not have any bottom padding. So below Item 1-2,Item 2-2, Item 6 and Item 10 should be padding. And there should always be the same padding, so below Item 2-2 should still be 20px and not 40px.

I tried

```
.sub-menu:not(:last-child){
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     }
```

but it is not working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: All your sub-menus are last children - try taking out the not and put in something like background: red - they all will be colored.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the following combination of CSS rules. Note: The `!important` in the second rule is necessary for specifity reasons, otherwise it would not overwrite the first rule where it applies.

I also added a red background to the affected elements to make it more obvious.

```css
nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) > ul.sub-menu > li:last-child,
nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li:last-child {
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 20px;

}
nav > ul li.menu-item-has-children {
  background: none !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul><li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Shop</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1-1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1-2</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2-1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2-2</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 4</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 5</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 6</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Legal</span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 7</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 8</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 9</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 10</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 11</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 12</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 13</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Item 14</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question maybe wasn't 100 % clear. Yozr code works almost like I need, except: The submenus that I have are hidden by default and only opened when clicked on. So if you click on "Shop", you ee "Item 1" and "Item 2" (without their respetive submenus), so there needs to be padding below "Item 2" as well. But if you click on "Item 2", and the submenu from that item opens, there should be only 20px at the bottom instead of 20px from "Item 2" and 20 px from "Item 2-2". Does that make sense?